# Squaring up photo into Google Earth using spatial adjustment

Tags: google-earth, curvature, spatial-adjustment, rubbersheeting

I have a photo such as:

[image: photo]

that I want to add into a Google  Earth  map. I know where the image must be: North: 44°16'48.00"N, South: 35°15'0.00"N, East: 4°42'0.00"E, West: 10°1'12.00"O and I have obtained this:

[image: google earth with photo]

I think I can adjust the photo into the Google Earth  photos with software such as QGIS but how do I do that?

Comment: I think you should search on spatial adjustment or rubbersheeting.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks for your help, do you have any idea of what do I have to do next? Thanks!

Comment: Google Earth cannot do rubbersheeting so you could try ArcGIS Pro (or ArcMap) which certainly can.